# XSLT: call only part of a template

Tags: xslt

Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to call only a part of a template?

I have a large template which I must use, yet the first two lines in the template need to be adjusted/changed.

How can I do this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance
Greets

Comment: Perhaps you could add a *parameter* to the call?

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more? How that would exactly work?

Comment: Uhm.. why don't *you* explain a little bit more about your need - perhaps provide an example? Otherwise this would turn into a tutorial, which has no place here. Do, however, search for "call XSLT template with parameter".

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. The thing is that I have a template which translates xml into html. The template now starts with 2 lines of html code. The template is used many times in the application and therefore I cannot change the template, yet i need to change those two lines at the top somehow. That is my goal. I don't quite see though how I can manage that with the parameter call.

Comment: like said, xsl:param received to the template and xsl:if that checks the value of this parameter, and executes part of the template

Comment: If you need to **change** those two lines to something else, use `<xsl:choose>` to select between the two versions. If you only need to either **include** them or not, you can use `<xsl:if>`. In both cases, the passed parameter would be used to make the decision, e.g. name the parameter "version" and test for `$version='alt'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor the large template so that it calls the first couple of lines as a child template or function which can then be called directly from outside.

It's generally true in XSLT as in any other language that templates/functions have a habit of growing too big, which reduces the reusability of the code, and the answer to this is always to be prepared to refactor the code to isolate the reusable parts into individually callable (and overridable) components.

Answer (score -1):

Since XSLT files have XML format, you could have an XSLT script that changes the original template as needed. After that you use that changed template to do the actual work.

Comment: sorry but you are not answering what he asked

Comment: Why not? He wants to use a template, but has to change it. With my suggested answer all future changes to the original template will be covered and he will be able to make the changes without changing the original code. What is wrong with that exept it isn't what you suggested? Your suggestion needs to edit the original code - what makes you shure that is possible?

Comment: See the above comments and their direction, yours is like answering someone who wants to know how to do an `if` in his `c` program, to write a perl script that modifies his `c` code

Comment: I can't accept downvoting without understandig the point: I didn't suggest something completely diffent like perl from c, it's all plain XSLT. Why peek with parameters if a two-pass-solution will do? This is a platform do get hints in different directions. I wanted to be helpful, why do you think I should be punished for that? I can't see where I missed the point. Can you explain, nrathaus?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer and explain what exactly "an XSLT script that changes the original template as needed" means. I for one wouldn't know what to do if given such advice, not even what to look for.